# How to implement an enumerator in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, proxy, enumerator

How can an enumerator be implemented in AS3?  I would like to loop over objects with a `for each` loop, such that I can traverse all the objects in a tree or a display list.

I would imagine that the Proxy class could come in handy, with its nextName, nextNameIndex, nextValue, and getProperty methods.

Comment: You answered your own question in your last sentence.

Comment: That's not an answer, it's a hint.  And I very often post questions that I already know the answer to and intend to post an implementation that I already have, simply as a contribution to the community.  I'm also interested in seeing others' implementations and possible solutions I may not have thought of already.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my implementation of a display list enumerator, which will traverse the children of a DisplayObjectContainer in a depth-first manor:

```
package flos.utils 
{
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer;
    import flash.utils.flash_proxy;
    import flash.utils.Proxy;
    import flos.system.IDisposable;

    public class DisplayListEnumerator extends Proxy implements IDisposable
    {
        private var list:Vector.<DisplayObject>;
        private var root:DisplayObjectContainer;

        public function DisplayListEnumerator( root:DisplayObjectContainer )
        {
            this.root = root;
        }

        public function dispose():void
        {
            root = null;
        }

        private function get disposed():Boolean
        {
            return root == null;
        }

        private function enumDisplayList():void
        {
            var _childIndex:int = 0;
            var _childIndexStack:Vector.<int> = new Vector.<int>();
            var _currentContainer:DisplayObjectContainer = root;
            var _current:DisplayObject;
            list = new Vector.<DisplayObject>();
            enumerate: do
            {
                for (var i:int = _childIndex; i < _currentContainer.numChildren; i++)
                {
                    _current = _currentContainer.getChildAt( i );
                    list.push( _current );
                    if (_current is DisplayObjectContainer)
                    {
                        _childIndexStack.push( i + 1 );
                        _childIndex = 0;
                        _currentContainer = _current as DisplayObjectContainer;
                        continue enumerate;
                    }
                }
                if (_currentContainer == root)
                    break enumerate; //break when we finish enumerating the root element
                else
                {
                    _childIndex = _childIndexStack.pop();
                    _currentContainer = _currentContainer.parent;
                }
            } while (true);
        }

        override flash_proxy function nextNameIndex( index:int ):int
        {
            if (disposed)
                throw new Error( "Enumerator disposed." );
            if (index == 0) //initial call, cache the current display list in a vector
            {
                enumDisplayList();
                return 1;
            }
            else if (index < list.length)
                return index + 1;
            else
                return 0;
        }

        override flash_proxy function nextName( index:int ):String
        {
            if (disposed)
                throw new Error( "Enumerator disposed." );
            var i:int = index - 1;
            if (i > -1 && i < list.length)
                return String(i);
            else
                return null;
        }

        override flash_proxy function nextValue( index:int ):*
        {
            if (disposed)
                throw new Error( "Enumerator disposed." );
            var i:int = index - 1;
            if (i > -1 && i < list.length)
                return list[i];
            else
                return undefined;
        }
    }
}
```

Since the enumerator extends the Proxy class and implements its enumeration-related methods, it can be used in a for each loop like so:

```
import flos.utils.DisplayListEnumerator;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer;

var i:int = 0;
for each (var d:DisplayObject in (new DisplayListEnumerator( root as DisplayObjectContainer )))
    trace( (i++) + " " + d.name );
```

Of course, this can probably be implemented without pre-indexing the display list, but that would require additional checks, such as making sure the index in the call to nextNameIndex isn't called out of order (and is actually incremented by one from call to call), maintaining a stack of where the enumeration is at each level in a non-recursive fashion just like I do in the implementation above, and also any solution that does not index the display list as a single operation one would run the risk of errors** or even infinite loops if the display list is changed at all during enumeration.  The implementation I've provided here which takes a snapshot of the display list when enumeration beings is probably the most stable.

**Having also implemented the non pre-indexing version myself, I can tell you that they are in fact less stable, especially if you're doing any kind of debugging, since the debugger will attempt to enumerate the enumerator's properties when you step into the code, immediately corrupting the active enumeration state, so the implementation I've provided above (specifically a type of implementation that pre-caches the display list in a single step) when enumeration begins may in fact be the only stable way to implement this.

Here is the non pre-indexing version, which rather than indexing the entire display list when enumeration beings, it just traverses the display hierarchy node by node at each iteration of the for each loop.  This type of implementation experiences interference from the debugger's "locals" window however, which tries to "enumerate the enumerator" (something Visual Studio actually warns you about), so I suggest against using the following type of implementation:

```
package flos.utils 
{
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer;
    import flash.utils.flash_proxy;
    import flash.utils.Proxy;
    import flos.system.IDisposable;

    public class DisplayListEnumeratorRealtime extends Proxy implements IDisposable
    {
        private var list:Vector.<DisplayObject>;
        private var root:DisplayObjectContainer;
        private var _enumIndex:int;
        private var _parentStack:Vector.<DisplayObjectContainer>;
        private var _childIndexStack:Vector.<int>;
        private var _childIndex:int;
        private var _current:DisplayObject;
        private var _currentContainer:DisplayObjectContainer;

        public function DisplayListEnumeratorRealtime( root:DisplayObjectContainer )
        {
            this.root = root;
        }

        public function dispose():void
        {
            root = null;
        }

        private function get disposed():Boolean
        {
            return root == null;
        }

        private function reset():void
        {
            _childIndexStack = new Vector.<int>();
            _parentStack = new Vector.<DisplayObjectContainer>();
            _currentContainer = root;
            _current = null;
            _enumIndex = 0;
            _childIndex = 0;
        }

        private function pushChild():void
        {
            _parentStack.push( _currentContainer );
            _childIndexStack.push( _childIndex + 1 );
            _childIndex = 0;
            _currentContainer = _current as DisplayObjectContainer;
        }

        private function popChild():void
        {
            _childIndex = _childIndexStack.pop();
            _currentContainer = _parentStack.pop();
        }

        override flash_proxy function nextNameIndex( index:int ):int
        {
            if (disposed)
                throw new Error( "Enumerator disposed." );
            if (index == 0) //initial call, cache the current display list in a vector
                reset();

            if (index == _enumIndex) //ensure expected index is passed
            {
                _enumIndex = index + 1;
                processNextChild: do
                {
                    if (_childIndex < _currentContainer.numChildren)
                    {
                        _current = _currentContainer.getChildAt( _childIndex );
                        if (_current is DisplayObjectContainer)
                        {
                            pushChild();
                            return _enumIndex;
                        }
                        _childIndex++;
                        return _enumIndex;
                    }
                    else if (_parentStack.length > 0)
                    {
                        popChild();
                        continue processNextChild;
                    }
                    break;
                } while (true);
                if (_currentContainer == root)
                    return 0; //enumeration is complete when enumeration of the root element is complete
                return _enumIndex;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Error( "Enumeration index called out of order." );
            }
        }

        override flash_proxy function nextName( index:int ):String
        {
            if (disposed)
                throw new Error( "Enumerator disposed." );
            if (index == _enumIndex)
                return String(_enumIndex);
            else
                throw new Error( "Enumeration index called out of order." );
        }

        override flash_proxy function nextValue( index:int ):*
        {
            if (disposed)
                throw new Error( "Enumerator disposed." );
            if (index == _enumIndex)
                return _current;
            else
                throw new Error( "Enumeration index called out of order." );
        }
    }
}
```